# Why does getLayoutParams() throw exception when called inside some events? e.g., onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, android-layout, exception, android-event

I have a RelativeLayout with a one View object (a simple bitmap). I use getLayoutParams() and setLayoutParams() to move it, for the sake of compatibility.

But when getLayoutParams() is called from inside onSaveInstanceState() event (because screen rotated, for example), program aborts with message "The application ... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". Code:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        View v=findViewById(R.id.MyView);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;
        lp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();  // **Exception!!!**

        // ... (do something with lp.leftMargin, etc)

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

These are the relevant exception first lines:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
        at com.example.Main.onSaveInstanceState(Main.java:85)
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1037)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
```

The same happens inside onCreate() and onPause() events.

When I use getLayoutParams() inside other functions (e.g. timer event functions) it works fine.

Comment: Can you share the xml file please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getLayoutParams` returns a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. There are many, many subclasses of this, including `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Your `View` `v` must be returning the wrong type.

If you need to use `leftMargin` etc you should try replacing `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`. I can't be sure it'll work as I don't know the class of `v`.

Comment: Precise diagnostic! By mistake I was trying to obtain a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class out of a `(Layout).getLayoutParams()` function, instead from an `(ImgView).getLayoutParams`. So it was a simple typecasting error... I think I didn't fully read the first line of the exception: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException`.